# Installing binaries on Heroku, specifically FontCustom

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, webfonts

I'm building a web app on Heroku which will allow users to select n number of SVG icons, and package those icons into a font file for them. The core of the app is a project called [FontCustom](https://github.com/endtwist/fontcustom). Using a Gemfile for my project I'm able to install the fontcustom gem, but I'm at a loss on how to install the required binary dependencies `fontforge eot-utils ttfautohint` indicated in the readme.

1) Is it possible to install these libraries on my Heroku instance?

2) If it is, how do I do it?

Thanks in advance for any assistance. Appreciated.

Comment: if there are binary dependencies, you may need to make your custom buildpack. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Comment: Owen...would you assume that anything installed via brew would be a binary? And I say that with sincerity...I don't know for sure.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to install your binary dependencies by creating a custom buildpack. See this article for more info; https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries.

Comment: Owen...if you set yours as an answer I'll award the points to you.

Comment: I've never used buildpacks, but you can compile the dependencies yourself, include them in your repo (usually under bin/) and push them up to heroku. I did a quick writeup for using Subversion at http://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2012/11/21/fetching-changesets-in-redmine-from-heroku-using-svn/, which may also help get you moving in the right direction. This is assuming a buildpack doesn't fit the bill ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your custom libraries in `bin/` folder in your app, then include them in the environment variables `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when your app start.

Or you can make your own Heroku build-pack. Here is an example of [heroku-buildpack-fontforge](https://github.com/bernerdschaefer/heroku-buildpack-fontforge).

You can see how it works in [compile](https://github.com/bernerdschaefer/heroku-buildpack-fontforge/blob/master/bin/compile) and [release](https://github.com/bernerdschaefer/heroku-buildpack-fontforge/blob/master/bin/release) steps.